# Solution verification: solving $T(n) = T(n-1) + 2/n$

Tags: algorithms, recurrence-relation

I was wondering if someone could possibly verify my solution to the following:

I'm trying to solve the recurrence relation $T(n) = T(n-1) + 2/n$. To get it into the form of the Master Theorem, I note that for sufficiently large $n$, $n - 1 \geq n/2$. Moreover, $2/n = O(1)$. Thus, we can rewrite the equation as $T(n) = T(n/2) + O(1)$. Since $\log_21 = 0$, it then follows directly from the Master Theorem that $T(n) = O(\log(n))$.

-Thanks!

Comment: 1) $n-1 \geq n/2$ implies that you derived a *lower* bound ($\Omega$). 2) "check my answer" questions are bad for this platform. 3) See [our reference question](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/2789/solving-or-approximating-recurrence-relations-for-sequences-of-numbers).

Comment: Master theorem does not apply in your case

Answer (score 4):

Although the final result is correct, your solution is not.

The recurrences of the form $T(n) = T(n-1) + 2/n$ is often called "decrease and conquer"; while the ones of the form $T(n) = T(n/2) + O(1)$ is called "divide and conquer". Generally, they are different and cannot be reduced to each other.

**Hint:** To solve $T(n) = T(n-1) + 2/n$, you can expand it and notice that $1 + 1/2 + \cdots + 1/n = H(n) = \Theta(\lg n)$, the $n$-th [partial sum of the harmonic series (wiki)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_(mathematics)#Partial_sums).

Answer (score 2):

No, this solution is unfortunately false. You remark that for sufficiently large $n$, $n-1 \geq n/2$ (indeed, $n \geq 2$ would do). The recurrence easily implies that $T$ is increasing, so $n-1 \geq n/2$ implies that $T(n-1) \geq T(n/2)$. All you can deduce is that $T(n) \geq T(n/2) + 2/n$, which cannot imply any upper bound on $T(n)$. Even the lower bound you get is only $\Omega(1)$.

If you forget about the Master Theorem, then you can notice that
$$
\begin{align*}
T(n) &= T(n-1) + \frac{2}{n} \\ &= T(n-2) + \frac{2}{n-1} + \frac{2}{n} \\ &= \cdots \\ &= T(0) + \frac{2}{1} + \cdots + \frac{2}{n} \\ &= T(0) + 2H_n,
\end{align*}
$$
where $H_n = \sum_{k=1}^n (1/k)$ is the $n$th Harmonic number. It is well-known that $H_n = \log n + \Theta(1)$ (indeed, the complete asymptotic series is known), and so $T(n) = 2\log n + \Theta(1)$.